# VSCode: keybindings.json won't be effective

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have added those lines to use tab instead of arrows to choose a code from suggestions. Yet, it does not change anything when I am coding in python. Is my way to write the keybindings correct?

Also, I am using Pylance as the language server. And VScode automatically made `.vscode` directory in the working directory which contains `setting.json` that states my python executable path, would it be the cause of the problem?

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "-acceptSelectedSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "down",
        "command": "-selectNextSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+tab",
        "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "up",
        "command": "-selectPrevSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Pylance as the language server. And VScode automatically
> made .vscode directory in the working directory which contains
> setting.json that states my python executable path,would it be the cause of the problem?

On the contrary, this two provide great convenience for your development. `Pylance` supports awesome features like auto-import, code completion and etc, and the folder `.vscode` is for your current workspace escaped from clutter global environment. You can watch it clearly what's configured in workspace settings.json about the current project.

Here is the solution:

`Tab` is for selectNextSuggestion, and `Shift+Tab` is for selectPrevSuggestions:

```
    {
        "key": "tab",
        "command": "selectNextSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "down",
        "command": "-selectNextSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+tab",
        "command": "selectPrevSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "up",
        "command": "-selectPrevSuggestion",
        "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus"
    },
```